# Is it possible to disconnect a bluetooth connection using Applescript?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, applescript

I want to disconnect a connection to a bluetooth device through an Applescript. Please note that I *don't* want to disable or enable bluetooth, I just want to disable one specific connection.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I use for disconnecting my Samsung Soundbar. Also remember that you need to give permission to application to use `SystemUIServer` steps for that.

`System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility > [name_of_your_application]`

One little remark: you need to have bluetooth icon on your menu bar.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    set bt to (first menu bar item whose description is "bluetooth") of menu bar 1
    click bt
    tell (first menu item whose title is "[Samsung] Soundbar") of menu of bt
        click
        tell menu 1
            if exists menu item "Disconnect" then
                click menu item "Disconnect"
            else
                click bt -- close main dropdown to clean up after ourselves
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Works well.  I wouldn't have thought to do it via the menu bar, but it works great.  Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth functionality isn't made available through the Mac OS APIs (System Events being the chief one for things like this). You should be able to do this with GUI scripting ([a great intro can be found on the Mac OS X automation site](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html)), but this is a really wonky way of doing it and is error-prone (unexpected dialog windows being the single biggest problem).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, my bluetooth has been b0rk3d for quite some time, but

```
man networksetup
```

You should be able to say something like

```
networksetup -getInfo <interface>
```

and then you could use the vast array of tragically randomly capitalized switches to work your will upon your bluetooth device, which should be a network interface.

OR

You want to disable one connection, and one connection alone?

```
/sbin/ipfw -q add deny ip from <bluetooth interface> to [any|badguy.com]
```

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way. I'm not talking about a bluetooth PAN or something like this. I refer to a simple bluetooth connection between a Human-Input Device (HID) and my Macbook.