# Turn on bluetooth via terminal/command line

Tags: terminal, bluetooth

How can I turn on bluetooth via the terminal / the command line?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/is-it-possible-to-disconnect-a-bluetooth-connection-using-applescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer over at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/92804/how-to-enable-bluetooth-in-mac-with-shortcut-or-command-line). The last post there is what I found to work best, in a slightly different form. The 'checkbox "On"' did not work for me, but the following code did:

```
# This is only necessary, if AppleScripts are not yet allowed to change checkboxes
tell application "System Events" to set UI elements enabled to true
# Now change the bluetooth status
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preferences.bluetooth"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            # Enabled is checkbox number 2
            if value of checkbox 2 of window "Bluetooth" is 0 then
                click checkbox 2 of window "Bluetooth"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

You can execute this script using [osascript](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=AppleScript/2.1/en/as164.html).

Update: I now changed the script to just enable Bluetooth. No toggling anymore.

Comment: Awesome. I have put this into a shell script and added `osacript <<SCRIPT` in front of it and at the end `SCRIPT` and it works fine! Thanks

Comment: Can you add at the bottom the old code to toggle?

Comment: Andrew: just remove the if around the "click checkbox 2...". That should do the trick.